# Build error when using [FromService] decorators in controller with Functions v3

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, azure-functions

I have created a new projected, where I am trying to use `[FromServices]` with `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.13"` and `"Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0"`.

There are some tickets opened on this subject. For example this [one](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-vs-build-sdk/issues/435#issuecomment-656854953).
I haven't seen any response/solution from Microsoft.
Is there an incompatibility between libs, what is the combination that I should use?
If this method injection doesn't work, can you please tell me what other alternatives do I have?

Startup.cs

```
    using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
    using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Extensions;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

    [assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(Startup))]
    namespace SubscriptionManager.Functions
    {
        public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
        {
            public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
            {
                builder.Services.AddTransient<IAccountService,     AccountService>();
                builder.Services.AddScoped<ISubscriptionService, SubscriptionService>();
            }
        }
    }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The .Net version comaptible with `"Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0"` is  .NETStandard 2.0.
Please refer the [Document](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions/).

Comment: Hi, in my Startup.cs I have the code pasted above, where I use [assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(Startup))] and this FunctionsStartup is from Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection. The latest version I can see is 1.1.0. How can I replace this or how should the Startup look like?

Comment: What is the .Net Framework version you are using ?

Comment: <PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  <AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
 </PropertyGroup>
 <ItemGroup>
  <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
 </ItemGroup>

Comment: Update your .Net Version to V4 and check.

Comment: Do you mean to use <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>? This is also a problem that I have in a project migrated from Azure functions 2.2 to 3.1. I also need to make it work in the migrated project, so just changing AzureFunctionsVersion to v4 would be enough?

Comment: Do not add V4 manually, Update your frameworks from Nuget Packages to the Latest Version.